# SQL Server Data Tools in VS Community

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I installed `VS Community` and `SQL-Server Express 2014` on my machine. According to [this page](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-server-data-tools-sql-server-2014)

> "DTS is now SSIS is now SSDT is now SSDT-BI."

And

> "Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web, Express for Windows Desktop,
>   Professional, Premium, and Ultimate include the SSDT tools(SQL server Data tools)".

I do not have the tools in my `VS Community` nor does the `SQL-Server Express 2014` give my any tools. I am confused and do not know what to install to get the "`SQL Server Data Tools`". A `180 Expire version` would be enough for test purposes. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Are you searching for Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 ?

Comment: EXpress Edition doesn't have Data Tools http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/overview.aspx
You can try this link... https://msdn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/data/hh297027 I always was using standart version...

Comment: @utility: I am looking for the vs extention to configure ssis. All the tutorials use the SSDT for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42313 and now SSDT-BI is available in Visual Studio Community 2013.